# Which law of state of California requires sellers to have a smog certificate?

Tags: california, vehicle

The DMV website says that "a seller must provide evidence of a current smog certification", but they don't cite which law obligates a seller in doing so. Which law states that?

What if the seller sells a car without a smog certificate, which penalties is the seller subject to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[California Code 24007(b)(2)](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=veh&group=23001-24000&file=24000-24018):

> Prior to or at the time of delivery for sale, the seller shall
>   provide the purchaser a valid certificate of compliance or
>   certificate of noncompliance, as appropriate, issued in accordance
>   with Section 44015 of the Health and Safety Code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know also what penalties are assessed to a seller who sells without smog certificate? Is sale rescinded in such cases? Do you know any references for previous lawsuits?